# install Weblogic 12.2.1.3 on Windows 10 without Admin rights

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c

I need to install `Weblogic 12.2.1.3` server on Windows without Administrator rights.

I followed the official guide and used `java -jar fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar` but it failed with the following error:

```
2019-07-23 17:02:05,062 SEVERE [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Utils - Invalid Central Inventory location "C:\PROGRA~1\Oracle\product\12.2.0.1\oraInventory" (path contains invalid character(s)).
```

I think it failed because I do not have write permission for the mentioned directory. So I did some research on the internet for the solution.

**What I have tried:**

- use `-invPtrLoc` option: `Ignoring option "-invPtrLoc" (not applicable on Windows).`
- `set INST_LOC=c:\Users\abc\dev\applications\oracle`: no result
- `set inventory_loc=c:\Users\abc\dev\applications\oracle`: no result

Do you have any idea what is the proper way to configure the installer to use different path for Oracle Inventory location?

ps: I am not allowed to execute random `exe` files on my computer so exe install packages are not options for me.

Comment: Windows 10 supports `docker-for-windows`. Perhaps see if you can have that activated on your desktop and then you can download `Weblogic` from `DockerHub` without any of these challenges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use a path without special characters like space. Even if you succeed in installing weblogic you will experience some difficulties when running servers without admin rights. Server start can be longer, patch list will not be available in the console and patching the product can be impossible. Maybe you can use a Windows VM with which you can have admin rights.